# gunicorn killing workers repeatedly with no traffic

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask app running on top of gunicorn which works fine on centos8 and rhel8. I'm trying to bring the app up on an rhel8 derivative which is hardened for FIPS/military compliance. This new os constantly sees workers timing out with no REST traffic offered.

The keepalive files are not having their timestamps updated by the worker threads which leads the arbiter to kill them off. I've added enough debug code to know that much.

I've studied the code and see that gunicorn uses a notify mechanism which relies on updating the permissions on temporary files. I've been looking around for these files but can't seem to find them. I've looked in /tmp (which I believe to be the default) and even set --worker-tmp-dir /tmp/gunicorn with no luck. Both are empty.

Any advice on how to proceed here will be appreciated.

```
[root@host-172-23-14-219 ~]# ls -ltr /tmp/gunicorn/
total 0
[root@host-172-23-14-219 ~]# ls -latr /tmp/gunicorn/
total 0
```

These are the messages I see in the debug output. The repeat every 30 seconds which is the default value for timeout. If I change the timeout, the time before being killed increases.

```
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [9120] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14483)
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [9120] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14485)
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [9120] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14488)
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [14483] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14483)
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [14485] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14485)
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [14488] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14488)
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [14782] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14782
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [9120] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [14783] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14783
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [14785] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14785
[2021-01-15 16:33:21 +0300] [9120] [DEBUG] 3 workers
```

Complete trace running gunicorn from the command line.

```
[root@dbaas1 restapi]# /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --log-level debug --log-syslog --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 -m 007 wsgi:app
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942060] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: None
  bind: ['127.0.0.1:5000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 3
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 30
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /opt/rbbn/dbaas/src/serviceDiscovery/restapi
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 0
  group: 0
  umask: 7
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: True
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags: 
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: wsgi:app
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f13b046be18>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f13b046bf28>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f13b04860d0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f13b04861e0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f13b04862f0>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f13b0486400>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f13b0486510>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f13b0486620>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f13b0486730>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f13b0486840>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f13b04868c8>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f13b04869d8>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f13b0486ae8>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f13b0486bf8>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f13b0486d08>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942060] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942060] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942060] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (2942060)
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942060] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942066] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2942066
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942068] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2942068
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942069] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2942069
[2021-01-18 22:11:23 +0300] [2942060] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942060] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2942066)
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942060] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2942068)
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942060] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2942069)
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942066] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2942066)
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942068] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2942068)
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942069] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2942069)
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942357] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2942357
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942060] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942359] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2942359
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942360] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2942360
[2021-01-18 22:11:53 +0300] [2942060] [DEBUG] 3 workers
```

Comment: Discovered that keepalives are not working because each worker process is hung when calling load_wsgi(). This is where the Flask framework gets loaded. Specifically, gunicorn hangs when calling importlib.import_module() to pullin our flask app.

Comment: This problem can be replicated very simply by running the follow. The python interpreter never returns.
[root@ple5-dbaas1 restapi]# python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 18 2020, 08:33:21) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import __init__


On rhel8, the interpreter prompt returns after loading the module.

Answer (score 0):

Running into a similar problem - everything works fine on `Ubuntu 18.04`, but fails consistently with similar errors / logging on `Ubuntu 22.04`.

Try increasing `timeout` higher than `30` in gunicorn config / settings.

Changing the `timeout` to `90` was sufficient for me to get things working again - my best guess is that the initial load-in of the Flask app takes longer on some machines and so it's hitting this limit.